# How do I modify the item of an array passed as data context in a child template?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I have a local collection which stores arrays of odds:

```
ChecksCollection = new Mongo.Collection(null);
ChecksCollection.insert({
  odds: ['', ''],
  oddsAverages: ['', ''],
  oddsCompeting: ['', '']
});
```

And a helper that sets the parent data context:

```
Template.Step1.helpers({
  bet: () => ChecksCollection.findOne()
});
```

And now I need a child template that can modify any index of any array from the ChecksCollection. At the moment I call it like that:

```
{{>InputOdds odds=bet.odds.[0] label='The odds that are being offered to you:' placeholder='Any odds style works! Equivalent examples: 1/4   1.25   -400'}}

{{>InputOdds odds=bet.odds.[1] label='The odds offered for the opposite outcome:' placeholder=''}}
```

Later I might call it with {{#each ... in ...}} to loop through the oddsAverages for example.
This is the child template:

```
<template name="InputOdds">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="odds">{{label}}</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="odds" value="{{odds}}"
             placeholder="{{placeholder}}">
  </div>
</template>
```

Putting it more simply, my question is what to modify and what to write after the lines below in order to allow the child template to update the data context (therefore call update and modify values from the arrays of ChecksCollection):

```
Template.InputOdds.events({
  'keyup input.form-control': function (event, template) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this yey! If anyone is in the same situation, use the following code:

```
var objectForSet = {};
objectForSet[key + '.' + index] = value;
//todo remove debugging code from below. The line which creates the rendering problem is: ChecksCollection.update({}, {$set: objectForSet});
console.log(`Modifying local collection at key: ${key}; array index: ${index};`);
ChecksCollection.update({}, {$set: objectForSet});
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use meteor methods:
http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_methods

so you can do it like this:

server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  foo: function (arg1, arg2, arg2) {
   ChecksCollection.insert({
    odds: ['', ''],
    oddsAverages: ['', ''],
    oddsCompeting: ['', '']
  });
 }
)};
```

and then call the method:

```
Template.InputOdds.events({
  'keyup input.form-control': function (event, template) {
       //set up your data from the form
      Meteor.call('foo', data1, data2, data3);
      }
    )};
```

Comment: This is not the answer. For starters, it's a local collection, there's no point in using Methods.